# how to plot n=((pi-2phi)(1+2y^2)+sin(2phi)-8ycos(phi)) / ((pi-2phi)+sin(2phi)-4ycos(phi))

Tags: octave

```
>> y=-16:0.5:16; 
>> phi=linspace(0,4*pi,65);
>> a=((pi-2*phi)*(1+2*y.^2)+sin(2*phi)-(8*y*cos(phi)));
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x65, op2 is 1x65) #This is the error
>>b= ((pi-2*phi)+sin(2*phi)-4*y*cos(phi));
```

c=a/b;

The error is always that how can I resolve it? I want to plot the function c.

Comment: Use the operator `.*` instead of `*` for vector multiplication.

Comment: hi can I ask if the plot my program made was correct? I am in doubt of this sorry

Comment: You can put your function into WolframAlpha for verification. [Here's a starting point.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5B%28%28Pi+-+2+%CF%95%29+%281+%2B+2+y%5E2%29+%2B+Sin%5B2+%CF%95%5D+-+8+y+Cos%5B%CF%95%5D%29%2F%28%28Pi+-+2+%CF%95%29+%2B+Sin%5B2+%CF%95%5D+-+4+y+Cos%5B%CF%95%5D%29%2C+%7By%2C+-16.%2C+16.%7D%2C+%7B%CF%95%2C+0%2C+65.%7D%5D)